# How to show splash screen using Timer in android?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me How to show splash screen using Timer in android.I am able to show using thread ,But thread is good choice , can you please tell me the best way to handle this ?
Using thread  Like this

package com.example.splash_test;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected int _splashTime = 5000; 

    private Thread splashTread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         splashTread = new Thread() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {                       
                     synchronized(this){
                             wait(_splashTime);
                     }

                 } catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
                 finally {
                     finish();

                     Intent i = new Intent();
                     i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                             startActivity(i);

                     //stop();
                 }
             }
         };

         splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This snippet is very helpful to design a timer in short. Try this...

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }
}, 5000);
```

Here I'm starting `MainActivity` after 5 seconds.
Simply put this code into `onCreate()` of your splash activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

protected int _splashTime = 2000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    int secondsDelayed = 1;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    SecondActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
}

}
```

Comment: are you looking something like this Timer sTimer = new Timer();
  
     sTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                  startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
           AppMainActivity.class));
                  finish();
    
                 }
             });
         }
     }, 2000); // updates each 2 secs

Answer (score 1):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```

Answer (score 0):

Also u can insert in yours onCreate:

```
SystemClock.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
```

p.s. check this realisation of SplashScreen [link](https://github.com/cstew/Splash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/android/splash/App.java).

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Way**

```
Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
    }, 3000)
```